# How to read such figures with % as "up (by) 120%" and "increased (by) 120%". Do they mean the same?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

> [There are now 5.7 billion euros, in notes and coins, in circulation,
> ***up 120%*** from December 31 2001,......](https://www.theguardian.com/world/2002/dec/27/euro.eu)

> [Following significant media coverage of the statistics, calls and
> contacts logged on the following day – 6 April – were ***up by 120%***
> compared with the previous day.](https://www.theguardian.com/society/2020/apr/09/uk-domestic-abuse-helplines-report-surge-in-calls-during-lockdown)

> [Plastic bag regulation can have unintended consequences. Sales of
> small trash can liners ***increased 120%*** after bag bans](https://www.theguardian.com/society/2019/jun/09/plastic-bags-single-use-waste-everywhere-how)

> [Rough sleeping ***has increased by 120%*** in England but has fallen
> in Scotland.](https://www.theguardian.com/society/2018/dec/13/disgrace-rising-english-homelessness-includes-120000-children)

Such phrases describing growth rate as in the above examples are very common, but sometimes I'm confused about how to read them correctly.

My understanding is:

- If our 2019 sales are ***up 120%*** (or ***has increased 120%***) from year 2018, it means, for instance, US$ 100 million in 2018, and US$ 120 million in 2019
- If our 2019 sales are ***up by 120%*** (or ***has increased by 120%***) from year 2018, it means, for instance, US$ 100 million in 2018, and US$ 220 million in 2019

If the above understanding is correct, then how should I interpret "*..... is up 20% from last year*"? Is it different from "up 120% from last year"?

Or maybe those expressions include some ambiguities?

Comment: @Takashi As other answers have noted, they do mean the same thing. However, one thing that is **not** the same is when you say X is 120% *of* Y. This means that X is 20% more than Y is. In other words, X is six-fifths of Y.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

"Increased X%" or "increased by X%" or "up X%" or "up by X%" all mean the same. To increase an amount by a percentage is to take the original amount, and add to it the given percentage of that amount. Thus 'increased by 100%' means the same as 'doubled'. 100 increased by 120% is equal to `100 + (100 x 1.20)` which is 220.

[Percentage change calculator](https://www.skillsyouneed.com/num/percent-change.html)

It is common to use everyday fractions for some percentages, e.g. if something is increased by 25, 33.3, 50, or 75 per cent we can say it is increased by a quarter, a third, a half, or three quarters respectively.

In your question, you write:

> My understanding is:
>
> If our 2019 sales is up 120% (or has increased 120%) from year 2018,
> it means, for instance, US$ 100 million in 2018, and US$ 120 million
> in 2019

Your understanding is **not correct**. if your sales were $100 million in 2018 and $120 million in 2019, then they are up **20%** (or **have** increased **20%**) from 2018.

Comment: I agree with this answer, but note that there are plenty of mathematically illiterate journalists writing for our newspapers.  It's not uncommon to see "Increased by 20%"  used to mean "Changed from 60% to 80%.

Comment: @JamesK is perfectly correct and the use of _percentage point_ should be more widespread and perhaps would make a useful edit to the question. 60% to 80% is an increase of 20 percentage points or 33.3%

Comment: If you wanted to say that it was 100% and is now 120% (not 120% of 100%), you would say that it has increased **to** 120%, not **by** 120% or any of those other variants.

Comment: @DarrelHoffman - If something was 100 units in size or whatever and is now 120 units you can perfectly well say it has increased **by** 20%. This is normal English.

Comment: I didn't say "by 20%" was wrong - I said "by **1**20%" is wrong in that case, but "**to** 120%" is correct.

Comment: But nobody has said that 100 becoming 120 is increased **by** 120%, have they?

Comment: @MichaelHarvey They have: in the first bullet point, the questioner assumes that 100 becoming 120 is "increased 120%" and in this answer, you assert that "by" is equivalent to no preposition

Comment: @Timbo - absilutely correct. Apologies to DarrelHoffman. Answer amended.

Comment: @JamesK and let's not forget the mathematically illiterate marketing folks who call something that has tripled "3 times more" when that phrasing actually indicates a quadrupling.

Comment: If something has 'tripled 3 times' I would say it is 9 times bigger.

Comment: No, I meant that they use the phrase "3 times more" to indicate that something has tripled. But "3 times more" means "increased by 300%", e.g., going from 100% to 400% - a quadrupling.

Answer (score 0):

From a prescriptivist point of view, "X% increase" means "multiplied by (1+X/100)".

From a descriptivist point of view, "X% increase" is often *used* to mean "multiplied by X/100". Of course, if X<100, then it can only mean "multiplied by (1+X/100)". This results in the odd situation that "X% increase" suddenly means something different when X reaches 100.

Logically, "increased X times" should also mean "multiplied by 1+X", but its use to mean "multiplied by X" is even more common than "X% increase" as "multiplied by X/100".